# Database design for Google Maps data

Tags: android, database, google-maps-api-3

I am developing an Android application with Google Maps where user can find nearest locations closest to them. I am at the designing stage and I am trying to figure out what I need for my database in order to store locations. I understand that it uses longitude and latitude as two of the fields but what else is essential to make the app work? I've tried searching on SO and Google but obviously my searching skills are inferior.

Comment: How do we know what is essential to make your app work? All you have said is you want to store locations -- to me that means lat/lon, and perhaps some identifier like a name for the location.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apart from being closed  as not constructive, this question  may violate Google's terms of service  http://code.google.com/apis/maps/terms.html. Particularly  section 10.1.3 (a):

"You must not copy, translate, modify, or create a derivative work (including creating or contributing to a database) of, or publicly display any Content or any part thereof..."