# How to get nearest places (that are user entered) based on current location?

Tags: java, android, google-maps, location, google-maps-android-api-2

I am building an Android application where users can find nearest places according to their current location and also, be able to add places into the database. I understand that I will have to use long and lat in my database but I really don't know how to compare the current location against the places in the database. How would I even search it because I would potentially have to go through the entire database systematically pulling out each geo point and then comparing it against the user location?

Example:
Say users have entered 10 places in London and 1000 other places all around the world and a person in London is using the application and wants to find places that are nearest to them based on their current location. How would I search for these 10 places among 1000s of other places in the database? Performing distanceTo() a 1000 times is unnecessary.

Any advice, guides, tutorials, references would be great.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

This is my idea so far.

Get the longitude and latitude of the location, which could either have been searched, the current location or the location that the user has tapped on the screen.

With Long/Lat of said location - get the place description of the place from reverse geocoding with the getFromLocation method.

With place description, search database based on address string.

This is what I have right now but again this doesn't seem to be reliable. There must be a simpler way to query the database given the long/lat of a location and return back a complete list of the nearest spots.

Comment: Didn't you just ask that? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14698082/database-design-for-google-maps-data

Comment: No? That's a question on database design not programmatic searching? Sorry if it seems similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using latitude and longitude, this should be pretty simple.  Let's say the coordinates of the individual are roughly: 49°N, 2°E.

To find all locations with 1 square degree of lat/long, you would just select all locations that satisfied the following criteria:

- Latitude >= 48°N and <= 50°N

.. and ..

- Longitude >= 1°E and <= 3°E

Comment: Ah thanks, finally a constructive answer. How would this relate to the longitude and latitude returned from Google Maps/Android? 

I've used http://www.doogal.co.uk/LatLong.php as an example to get some geo points of London King's Cross Station and this is what is returned: Long - 51.530884, Lat - -0.1229.

Comment: At that point, I can't tell you how to implement it.  The only thing I can tell you is the criteria that you use to perform search.  I'm not familiar with the Google Maps API, so I don't know exactly how the concrete implementation would look.

Comment: It was helpful nevertheless, now I know I have some conversions to do of some sort. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty simple.

There's a table on Wikipedia that explains how much **decimal degrees are 1 kilometer** etc. And the coordinates that you receive from Google are in **decimal degrees**.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_degrees

If you have any more questions on how to calculate etc, just ask :)

Basically you just need to check if the places latitude is higher than

```
currentLocationLatitude - rangeInDecimalDegrees
```

and smaller than

```
currentLocationLatitude + rangeInDecimalDegrees
```